# How do I optimise this javascript function for speed?

Tags: javascript

I just took the Codility tape equilibrium test [here](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoR5JMJB-9KU/#)

As you can see from my score I didn't get good enough on how fast the function executes. Can anybody give me some pointers so I can optimise this code and get closer to 100%?

Here is the code...

```
function solution(A) {

    var minimumAbsDiff = null;

    for(var currentIndex =1;currentIndex < A.length;currentIndex ++){
        var bottomHalf = getTotal(0,currentIndex-1,A);
        var topHalf = getTotal(currentIndex,A.length-1,A);

         var absDiff = Math.abs(bottomHalf - topHalf);
         if(minimumAbsDiff == null){
            minimumAbsDiff = absDiff;
         }else{
            if(absDiff < minimumAbsDiff) minimumAbsDiff = absDiff;
         } 
    }

    return minimumAbsDiff;
}

function getTotal(start,end,arrayTocheck){
    var total = 0;
    for(var currentIndex = start;currentIndex <= end;currentIndex++){
        total = total + arrayTocheck[currentIndex];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: how do I move my post to it?

Comment: Try this http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: It suggests O(N) is the worst case acceptable time so I'd revisit the premise of a loop within a loop.

Comment: @Exitos: You'd need to repost it. Just copy/paste.

Comment: move `A.length` out of forloop, use `var len = A.length` then `currentIndex  < len` in for loop, to reduce array.length retrieve time.

Comment: @squint are you sure about that url?

Comment: @Mathletics: I'm sure I eff'd it up! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to optimise speed. You want to lower the [algorithmic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory). Your current algorithm is `O(n²)`, while the taks description explicitly stated that

> - expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
> - expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage
>     (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

So what's the insight to make that possible? Each total difference is only a small distance from the others for `P`. If you compare the value `|(A[0] + ... + A[P-1]) - (A[P] + ... + A[N-1])|` for `P` and `P+1`, there is only a constant amount of work difference to be done.

```
function solution(A) {
     var left = 0,
         right = A.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
     var min = Infinity;
     for (var p = 0; p<A.length-1; p++) {
         left += A[p];
         right -= A[p];
         min = Math.min(min, Math.abs(left - right));
     }
     return min;
}
```

Comment: @xdevel: Thanks, I missed that `P` must be neither `0` nor `N`

Comment: Cool and fast fix.! Awesome.!

Comment: @Exitos: check the wikipedia link "algorithmic complexity" in the answer

Comment: do you know any online tools where I can run functions and they will tell me how long they take to run without me having to write timers?